# How to read file using paths relative to context root in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am learning REST using Jersey. I was successful in creating the cliche Hello World application. Now (just for learning purposes) I am trying to return an image file through a byte stream. However, I get an `IOException` that the file cannot be read. Following is my Resource class :

```
@Path("/image/{file}")
public class ImageResource
{
   @Context
   private UriInfo uri;

   @GET
   @Produces("image/jpg")
   public Response getFullImage(@PathParam("file") String fileName)
   {
      Response response = null;
      String contextRoot = getUri().getBaseUri().toString();

      try
      {
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(contextRoot + "/images/" + fileName));
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
         byte[] imgBytes = baos.toByteArray();

         response = Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes)).build();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Error reading image file..." + e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return response;
   }

   private UriInfo getUri() {
      return uri;
   }

}
```

The image is stored under `WebContent/images/image001.jpg` and I am using the URL : `http://localhost:8080/REST/image/image001.jpg` to hit the resource.

Could someone please let me know the reason for the exception ???

Comment: is that a typo in the question or are you really hitting /REST/image/image001.jpg (singular image - should be images)

Comment: Am I not supposed to use the singular one since I have used the same in the `@Path` annotation? Please correct me if I am wrong. I am new to this :)

Comment: Oops, I missed that, what you've done ('image' in the URL, 'images' on the disk) is ok from a technical pov, but will surely cause confusion. If the resource is nested inside your jar/war you can't just create a File pointing to it, because it isn't a File in it's own right.

Answer (score 0):

Since the resource is embedded in your war/jar you need to use the ClassLoader to load it for you:

Something like:

```
@Path("/image/{file}")
public class ImageResource
{
   @Context
   private UriInfo uri;

   @GET
   @Produces("image/jpg")
   public Response getFullImage(@PathParam("file") String fileName)
   {
      Response response = null;
      String contextRoot = getUri().getBaseUri().toString();

      try
      {
         // load resource via classloader since it's embedded in war/jar
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ImageResource.class.
                                 getResourceAsStream(/images/" + fileName));
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
         byte[] imgBytes = baos.toByteArray();

         response = Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes)).build();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Error reading image file..." + e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return response;
   }

   private UriInfo getUri() {
      return uri;
   }

}
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working :(
I get a RunTimeException with the message `input==null` at this line:
`BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ImageResource.class.getResourceAsStream(/images/" + fileName));`

Answer (score 0):

You should acces to the image as a URL.
For me, this worked:

```
String path=uriInfo.getBaseUri().toString();
            path=path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/rest"))+"/img/"+foto;
            try {
                URL pathUrl=new URL(path);
                BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(pathUrl);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
                byte[] imgBytes=baos.toByteArray();
                 return  Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes)).build();
            }
```

Be sure that you don't include the restful path.